# How remove a "use of undeclared identifier: FIRDynamicLink"?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, firebase

We are following the dynamic instructions for Firebase [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios#open-dynamic-links-in-your-app), which lists just one import needed "@import Firebase" - yet when we get to their line

```
FIRDynamicLink *dynamicLink = [[FIRDynamicLinks dynamicLinks] dynamicLinkFromCustomSchemeURL:url];

if (dynamicLink) { ...
```

...XCode gives an undeclared identifier for FIRDynamicLink. Unlike some of the other modules like "import FirebaseAnalytics" - there doesn't seem to be another library dedicated to Dynamic Links.

The pod content is: pod "Firebase/DynamicLinks"

What is the trick to get this to compile?

Comment: what is the pod file content ?

Answer (score 8):

We solved this by adding the following import line. It wasn't mentioned in Google's documentation so we are unsure if it is the correct thing to do - but it does enable the app to compile.

```
@import FirebaseDynamicLinks;
```

Was this a simple oversight in their example code or are we misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 3):

It was working earlier. But due to some changes in podfile I was starting to get this irritating issue. Hence explicitly importing submodules satisfies compiler.

```
import FirebaseDynamicLinks
import FirebaseInstanceID
```

Answer (score 0):

I think they just confused between Objective-C and Swift. In swift they say to write this:

```
guard let dynamicLinks = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks() else {
return false
```

}

but it has to be like this:

```
guard let dynamicLinks = FIRDynamicLinks.dynamicLinks() else {
return false
```

}

So I think for Objective-C you should use this:

```
BOOL handled = [[DynamicLinks dynamicLinks] handleUniversalLink:userActivity.webpageURL
                                                      completion:^(DynamicLink * _Nullable dynamicLink,
                                                                   NSError * _Nullable error) {
                                                        // ...
                                                      }];
```